# RewriteRule creates 404 in SSL access log

Tags: .htaccess, access-log

I'm trying to get some nice URLs. I want to use 
https://sub.domain.edu/fs/7356
for 
https://sub.domain.edu/fs/index.php?ind=7356

My .htaccess for this directory is:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?ind=$1 [L,QSA]`

The page works fine in the browser. The PHP script works. It all looks great. But the ssl_access_log shows every page access as a 404.

"GET /fs/7356 HTTP/1.1" 404 9241

This would only be mildly annoying except logwatch flags all these 404s as possibly malicious probes. Every morning I get an email saying dozens of IPs tried to probe the site. I have tried adding R=301 to the RewriteRule but it does a full redirect to the full URL I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Try disabling the http server's `MultiViews` feature.

Comment: @arkascha Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a custom log format. In /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, I commented out the entry that created the ssl_acess-log file and replaced it with LogFormat and Customlog directives.

`#TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" logwatchfix
CustomLog logs/ssl_access_log logwatchfix`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

This resulted in a near-identical output as the original with the only exception being the "%>s" replaced with "%s" It works opposite the way I understand the documentation.

"%s Status. For requests that have been internally redirected, this is the status of the original request. Use %>s for the final status."

I would have thought the "status of the original request" would have been "404" and the "final status" after .htaccess redirection would be "200" In practice, in my case, it worked the opposite. I also placed similar .htaccess files in the other directories that worked the same way. I set the directory index to index.php instead of index.html in the httpd.conf file, but it seemed to make no difference.